# Binary Magic Cards

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, binary

There's a [cool magic trick](http://www.mathmaniacs.org/lessons/01-binary/Magic_Trick/) that works using the power of binary. The effect of the trick is as follows:

1. An audience member chooses some natural number in the range of `1 to x` where x is chosen by the magician.
2. The magician hands the audience member some special cards. Each card contains some numbers from `1 to x`.
3. The audience member selects the cards which contain their number.
4. Almost instantly, the magician can determine the original number selected.

---

## Specification:

The numbers used for the cards are determined based on binary place value. Each card is first labeled with a power of  2. The first card becomes 1, the second becomes 2, the third becomes 4, and so on.

From now on, I will refer to `card n` as the card labeled with `n`.

To determine whether a number `k` is on card `n`, determine whether k in binary has at 1 at place value n. Consider the numbers `k=13` and `n=4`.

K in binary is `1101`. The second digit (n=4) is 1, so `k=13, n=4` is a valid combination.

## Goal:

Given two natural numbers `0 < n < 128` and `0 < k < 128`, determine whether `n` appears on card `k`. Any reasonable input and output is allowed. Standard loopholes are banned.

This is code-golf, so the fewest **bytes** wins.

## [Test cases](http://www.mathmaniacs.org/lessons/01-binary/Magic_Trick/)

Comment: Better add the test cases directly here.

Comment: Also, what is *determine whether `k` in binary **has at 1 at place value `n`*** supposed to mean? Did you mean that the character in the binary representation of `k` at index `n` is `1`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Probably "at" should be "a" but not sure.

Comment: Also, what did you mean by *The **second** digit **(n=4)***. Did you refer to the *fourth digit*? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No, binary place value 4. So like the 4-s digit.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I don't understand your comment either :P **EDIT**: I understood. The exponent of `2` such that we reach `n` (`2^2 = 4`)!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You know how we have 1s digits, 10s digits, 100s digits, etc? Same logic applies here

Comment: Does the truthy/falsy value have to be consistent?

Comment: Why did you swap `n` and `k` at the end "determine whether `n` appears on card `k`"?

Comment: It does not seem at all clear if the input is the binary place or the minimum number on the card (most people seem to be assuming the latter) - first you say "From now on, I will refer to card n as the card labeled with n" then immediately you say "determine whether k in binary has at 1 at **place value** n.".

Comment: Why did you ask a question and put it on hold? Couldn't you simply delete it?

Comment: @rahnema1 Only moderators can delete answered questions (when the answerers received reputation for it). This is common if you want to abandon the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 5 bytes

```
._.&E
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=._.%26E&input=13%0A4&debug=0)

Notice the cute face `._.`

---

## How?

```
._.&EQ  -  Q means input and is implicit.

  .&    - Bitwise AND between:
    E     - The second input and
     Q    - The first input.
._      - Sign. 0 if it equals 0, 1 otherwise.
```

If inconsistent values are allowed:

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 3 bytes

No cute face this time `._.`

```
.&E
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%26E&input=13%0A4&debug=0)

Comment: +2 for cute face, -1 for removing it

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/t////hsb/TQA)

Bitwise AND Builtin

Comment: After I have seen your comments, I am not sure enitrely you understood. *binary place value* is `0` for `1`, `1` for `2`, `2` for `4`, `3` for `8` (`2^binary_place_value = n`). Is that what you do in your answer?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Now I am not entirely side I understand your comment :P I'm fairly sure this is correct since it checks if the 4s place is truthy, not if the 4th digit from the right is truthy.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The 4s place is the place where it adds 4 if it's 1, so 2^2. `2^n = binary_place_value`

Comment: If this is the intended input, then certainly simply `&` will do since the range is **[1,x]** and "Any reasonable input and output is allowed." implies truthy/falsey is fine.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 3 bytes

```
(&)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@19DTfN/QVFmXolGmoahsY6CiabmfwA)

(Waiting for pull from TIO before it works on TIO but you can verify it by cloning the repository)

Functional operator of the Bitwise AND operator

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
&Ā
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f7UjD//@GxlwmAA)